# php - curl query to backend, mix up data

Tags: php, json

I'm not sure if this question was asked before, but I couldn't find anything.

When I CURL to the back-end from the front-end, I pass a JSON object containing a SQL query in base64:

```
base64(SELECT * FROM mytable) -> U0VMRUNUICogRlJPTSBteXRhYmxl

[{
  'sql' : 'U0VMRUNUICogRlJPTSBteXRhYmxl'
}]
```

Back-end receives it, and then run that query over a sqlite3 database. It returns the data and put it into a JSON object:

```
[{
  'column 1' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 2' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 1 - data',
},{
  'column 1' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 2' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 2 - data',
},{
  'column 1' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 2' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 3 - data',
}]
```

and then returns it back with python flask server, I think with requests library.

My problem is that the JSON object that comes back doesn't look like the one above, but returns more like:

```
[{
  'column 2' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 1 - data',
},{
  'column 2' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 2 - data',
},{
  'column 2' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 3 - data',
}]
```

and I don't know why. I even tried to specify the SELECT statement as 
    SELECT "column 1", "column 2", "column 3" FROM mytable;

but still the same.

I can order it myself, but there isn't only 1 table to be queried.

My CURL code:

```
$query = $_POST['query'];

function safeQ($squery){
    $denied = ["update","delete","insert","create","alter","drop"];
    $squery = strtolower($squery);
    foreach($denied as &$deny){
        if (strpos($squery, $deny) !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

print(getQuery($query));

function getQuery($query){
    if (safeQ($query)){
        $data->sql = base64_encode($query);
        $jsonData = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init('https://www.example.com/api/sql_query');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonData))
        );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference in the JSON i'm not seeing?

Comment: @PaxVobiscum order of keys.

Comment: There's noting in provided code that does mysql queries.

Comment: Why should there be an order of keys? It is a key/value structure?

Comment: Yes I know that, but why does it mix it up, I just want to print all as it is, like column 1, then column 2 then column 3, some of the tables got a lot of columns, can't specify all of them to print in a way. Why doesn't it just add column 1 first, why is column 2 first? That is what I want to know.

Comment: @u_mulder Back-end is running the query as it is. I don't have back-end code.

Comment: When the structure goes in to memory, it does not worry about order. That is the point of a key/value structure. In python this evaluates to true `{'a':1,'b':2} == {'b':2,'a':1} `.

Comment: When I query directly to the database, then it works perfectly, but when I CURL to it and get sent back with JSON, then it mix it up.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum OK, but why? Why does it not just keep the structure? Also how can I fix this? Plus when I rerun it, it doesn't change, it stays the same as the previous run?

Comment: There is no such thing as `just keep the structure`. How do you guarantee they are right next to each other in memory?

Comment: Have you tried Order by to see what is going on ?

Comment: Order by only orders rows, not columns. But my main query run a Order By anyway, and still have the same affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question why, it is the same thing I said in the comments; when python is storing a dictionary, it does not care about order. Why the order turns out the way it does? That requires a more complicated knowledge of memory allocation that i'm currently capable of answering, but the point of using a key/value structure is not regarding the order the entries are in.

```
[{
  'column 2' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 1 - data',
},{
  'column 2' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 2 - data',
},{
  'column 2' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 3 - data',
}]
```

Is completely fine. If you start seeing this however;

```
[{
  'column 2' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 1 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 1 - data',
},{
  'column 2' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 3 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 3 - data',
},{
  'column 2' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 3' : 'row 2 - data',
  'column 1' : 'row 2 - data',
}]
```

It is a case for concern, since this time the array type structure got out of its original order.

You can make the following assertion yourself by opening an interpreter

```
>>> {'a':1,'b':2} == {'b':2,'a':1} 
True
```

Comment: OK I am going to make the structure manually then, yay... I'll mark your answer. But I would like to see a good explanation for exactly why, one day.